# word press loop slider

Tags: wordpress, slider

hello i have been working on a particular theme sports bootstrap theme for my football blog. I tried looping the slider of the theme but the theme keeps scattering, despite all my effort . I would really like any help i get thanks. below is the php code i have been working on

```
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="feature_news_carousel">
                <div id="featured-news-carousal" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    
                    <?php
                 $args = array(
            'category_name' => 'latest',
            'posts_per_page'=> 4
            );
            $uk_soccer = new WP_Query($args);
       
            if ( $uk_soccer->have_posts() ) : while ( $uk_soccer->have_posts() ): $uk_soccer->the_post();
        
                ?>   
                        <div class="item active feature_news_item">
                        <div class="item_wrapper">
                                <div class="item_img">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                </div> <!--item_img-->
                                <div class="item_title_date">
                                    <div class="news_item_title">
                                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item_meta"><?php echo get_the_date('M, j Y'); ?> at <?php the_time(); ?>,</a> by:<a href="#"><?php echo get_author_name(); ?></a></div>
                                </div> <!--item_title_date-->
                            </div>  <!--item_wrapper-->
                            <div class="item_content"><?php echo excerpt(15); ?></div>
                            </div><!--feature_news_item-->
                        <?php
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    ?>
                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <div class="control-wrapper">
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured-news-carousal" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured-news-carousal" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>


                        </div><!--carousel-inner-->
                        </div><!--carousel-->
                

                

                
            </div><!--feature_news_carousel-->
                    
            
                        </div><!--col-md-6-->
```

Comment: Define "scattering". It's hard to tell what you mean with just some PHP/HTML code. Do you have a live URL where people can see the issue? Alternatively, share a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so people can help you debug this issue.

Comment: the link to the project is https://prediction.442virals.com/ and it is scattering in the sense that instead of the slider to slide, it is arranging the post downwards. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code so your slider will work

```
<div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="feature_news_carousel">
                <div id="featured-news-carousal" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
                    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
                    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
                    
                    <?php
                 $args = array(
            'category_name' => 'latest',
            'posts_per_page'=> 4
            );
            $uk_soccer = new WP_Query($args);
       
            if ( $uk_soccer->have_posts() ) : 
$index = 0;
while ( $uk_soccer->have_posts() ): $uk_soccer->the_post();
        
                ?>   
                        <div class="<?php echo ($index == 0) ? 'active' : ''; ?>feature_news_item">
                        <div class="item_wrapper">
                                <div class="item_img">
    <img class="img-responsive" src="<?php the_post_thumbnail_url(); ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>">
                                </div> <!--item_img-->
                                <div class="item_title_date">
                                    <div class="news_item_title">
                                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="item_meta"><?php echo get_the_date('M, j Y'); ?> at <?php the_time(); ?>,</a> by:<a href="#"><?php echo get_author_name(); ?></a></div>
                                </div> <!--item_title_date-->
                            </div>  <!--item_wrapper-->
                            <div class="item_content"><?php echo excerpt(15); ?></div>
                            </div><!--feature_news_item-->
                        <?php
$index++;
    endwhile;
    endif;
    wp_reset_postdata();
    
    ?>
                        <!-- Left and right controls -->
                        <div class="control-wrapper">
                            <a class="left carousel-control" href="#featured-news-carousal" role="button" data-slide="prev">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-left" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                            <a class="right carousel-control" href="#featured-news-carousal" role="button" data-slide="next">
                                <i class="fa fa-chevron-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>


                        </div><!--carousel-inner-->
                        </div><!--carousel-->
                

                

                
            </div><!--feature_news_carousel-->
                    
            
                        </div><!--col-md-6-->
```